# Code Igniter lose charset

Tags: codeigniter, character-encoding

I'm using codeigniter but it loses charset every time.
What can cause this?

For example:

At my address bar

```
www.abc.com/def
www.abc.com/def/
```

My db is UTF-8
My config file - `$config['charset'] = 'ISO-8859-1';`

Comment: What do you mean by "loses charset", this might be HTML problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

take a look at **meta charset** part